# I want to find a way around transcoding while containing bitstream into a file

Tags: file, webrtc, decode, transcoding, recordrtc

Now that I added a recording function using RecordRTC with mediasoup, I would like to do away with transcoding during the process.
current dataflow :
[image]

Can I contain the bitstream into a file without decoding the bitstream into a video at client ends?

[image]

Comment: Hi, your data flow is not clear. Are you using RecordRTC on the client to record and send blob packets to the server via mediasoup and on the server you are transcoding it and saving it to a file. Now you want to skip the transcoding part?

Comment: it's the other way around. On client end, I can save the displayed video sent and decoded via mediasoup into a file using recordRTC, but now I want to save the bitstream sent via mediasoup into a file right away without getting the bitstream passed through decoder.